# Spivak Calculus 3rd Edition Chapter 1 Problem 4 (iii)

Tags: inequality

I'm not sure on arriving at the solution to $5-x^2 < -2$ .  I've got:

$5-x^2 < -2$
$-x^2 < -7$
$x^2 < 7$
$\sqrt x^2 < \sqrt 7$
$x < \sqrt 7$

But the actual solution is $x > \sqrt7$ or $x < -\sqrt7$

Can someone point me in the right direction on this, thanks.

Comment: $-a < -b \implies a \color{red} {>} b$.

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL!! $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. This is fundamental knowledge if you're going to proceed successfully with Spivak. And the correct solution is *not* just $\{x: x>\sqrt7\}$.

Comment: line 3 is wrong you need to change the sign < to >

Comment: @MathLover thanks

Comment: Thanks to all for the help

Comment: @TedShifrin - thanks, I've just updated the question to include $x < -\sqrt 7$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
-x^2 < -7\iff x^2> 7\iff|x|>\sqrt{7}.
$$
In the first step multiplying both sides of the inequality by $-1$ "flips" the inequality sign.